# For loop structure to add in bash

Tags: bash

I'm new to this and what I'm trying to do is create a simple adding script in bash.

I have to use a for loop. What I'm starting so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
for num in {1..15}

do
       echo $num
done
       echo$sum
```

I need help with how to make the for loop show for example if I type:

```
add 4 -3 2 8
```

it will output as:

```
4
-3
2
8
=11
```

How would I make it so the `$num` only show what I typed in such as the `'4 -3 2 8'` and negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$@` to get all parameters, and `$(())` to do arithmetic.

```
sum=0
for num in $@
do
    sum=$((sum + num))
done

echo $@ = $sum
```

I'll retag your question as `bash`; `d` is not appropriate.

Comment: If only there was bonus rep for doing other people's homework. +1

Comment: The $@ must be quoted to be recognized as separate values, else: the split+glob operator takes control. both in `for num in "$@"` and the final echo: `echo "$@ = Ssum"`. I short: quote your expansions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to create an exit error to expand on the previous script now. if I type anything but a number now and what I have tried so far is:

```
sum=0
for num in "$@"
do
   echo $num | grep -i [^0-9+-]
 if ["$?" = 1] then
   echo "Sorry, '$num' is not a number"
 fi

    sum=$((sum + num))  
done
    echo $sum
```

Example if I type in

```
add 1 2 3 four five
```

it would say

```
 four
 Sorry, 'four' is not a number
```